# Start and End Iteration fields not available in Column Options in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, iteration

I'm looking to add the columns "Start Iteration" and "End Iteration" in Columns Options in Azure DevOps backlog but these two fields are not available. Does anyone have an work around for these issue?

I only see Start Date and Target Date, but I wanted to have something like, this feature started on Sprint 3 and will remain open until Sprint 7.

Comment: For that kind of view, I feel like you'd be better served by the [delivery plans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/plans/review-team-plans?view=azure-devops) feature rather than trying to fit it on the backlog view.